# C - sending different datatypes over TCP at once

Tags: c, sockets, networking, tcp, byte

I want to send some stuff over TCP, including int8_t, uint32_t, char, .... and I need to send it at once, so I was thinking about using one big byte array - especially since the receiver will treat the incoming packet as a byte array.

What's the proper way to do this in C? Since there's no "byte" datatype, I'm thinking about just using a int8_t array, filling it and sending it via FreeRTOS. What's stuff I should be aware of? Should I cast every value to int8_t (while splitting up larger ones with bit operators)? Anything I should take care of when trying to put unsigned data types in there?

Thanks for any help, haven't found much online surprisingly.

Comment: The process is called "serialisation" - turning your runtime data into a format that can be sent over a network (or any other remote end point). There are many different serialisation frameworks with different use cases and tradeoffs. Or you can roll your own. But they all have to solve similar problems such as framing, deep copying, compression or no-compression, text or binary, etc. This is a big topic and not that suitable as a Stackoverflow question. Suggest you research serialisation, try something and then come back with more specific questions as needed.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, will do so!

Comment: Just one extra note on your use of "at once". You may already know but TCP is a streaming protocol. That means there is no support for individual messages - e.g. even if the sender calls `send` twice each with size X it does not mean the receiver will get it in two `recv` calls. It may get it all in one `recv` or even in more than 2. That's why "framing" is needed - the sender and receiver need to know how to detect the end of one "message" and the start of the next. For example, fixed sized messages is one simple framing but that is not suitable for all use cases.

Comment: Anyway there's no need to cast your message structs to array of bytes: just provide the pointer to your struct to `send ()` along with its size, and as soon as `size` bytes will be received on the other side the receive buffer will automatically contain the sent struct (you just need to manage any particular struct packing policy). It would be easy to explain on a code example if you had shared some code..

Comment: @Cubo78 No. You should not use `struct`s as network protocols. Use network protocols as network protocols. Sending `structs` directly exposes you to quite a few points of failure.

Comment: @user207421I know, and the struct packing would be one of them (another one is endianess). It was just a speculative answer to a speculative question, so that sending the struct is at least better than casting the same data to an attay of 8 bytes integers... Nevertheless we can say that under certain conditions, if you control both sender and receiver application, even sending a struct could make the deal. You just need to know what you are doing (like in everything).

Comment: I'm aware it was a pretty broad question without much detail, sorry. In short, I'm just sending one message (for a long time), and the receiver both knows which size to expect and what the message should contain (eg. 4 bytes magic number, X bytes int8_t data, Y bytes uint32_t data)... so the struct approach could work. In general, would it be better (than using an int8_t array) to use a void buffer, allocate enough memory and then just memcpy all data?

Comment: Since you'd need all these instructions to copy the separated values into that buffer, why not hand them over to `send()` directly? As @Cubo78 said, provide the very same pointer and size. The code size is smaller, your intentions are clear, and you save the extra memory.

Comment: This sadly won't work because I have to gather the data outside of the WiFi and only afterwards I'm able to start the TCP connection.